# Moving files with the same name to matching named folders

Tags: powershell

Beginner and I'm stuck.

```
$filter= "Alive"
$source="D:\Users\Heather's\VendorScans\*"

Get-ChildItem -recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |Select-Object fullname | Where-Object {$_.fullname -match $filter} 
$destination= (Where-Object {$_.fullname -match $filter})

Copy-Item $source -destination $destination -recurse
```

Initial problem is moving files that are named for example "Alive" to a folder called "Alive".
So I'm trying to copy files from a Subfolder within a directory folder and I'm moving it to a double nested subfolder on the same drive. So `D:\Users\Heather's\VendorScans\*` to `D:\Users\Heather's\Vendors\AliveHospice`. Etc. The destination will change depending on if it matches the file name. The only problem is when I run this, it drops the files in the main directory so `D:\Users\Heather's` instead of going to the fullname path. If anyone could link me to some helpful resources or nudge me in the right direction I'd be grateful. Still not sure how to access subfolders or create unique destinations. Do I need a loop?

Comment: The `Get-ChildItem` line does a lot of filtering through the pipeline, but the end result isn't saved, it leaves the pipeline, and presumably just prints to the screen. (`PSIsContainer` means it includes only folders, but you talk about wanting files?). The next line `$destination=...` calls `where-object` with no input, and saves the empty output - so the destination of `Copy-Item` is empty. You probably do need a loop, or two, but I don't really understand what you're doing - can you give an example of what file might move from where to where? How does the destination change with filenames?

Comment: Is the destination folder name/location known? Is it a fixed path? Relative to the file or source folder? A completely arbitrary location?

Comment: The source will always be the same (vendorscans folder) and the destination is relative to what filter I select. (In my final version I will have something like ( $filter=Read-Host "Please enter a filter name.) The script should read the file name and move or copy the file to a folder on the same D drive (likely a subfolder) with the same name. Also thank you for the Get-Childitem explanation, I thought I could save its result into a variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have well understood what you were willing to do, here is the corresponding code :

```
 $filter= "Alive"
 $source="D:\Users\Heather's\VendorScans"
 $destination ="D:\Users\Heather's\VendorScans"
 set-location $source

 $source_regex = [regex]::escape($source)
 (Get-ChildItem $source -recurse | where {-not ($_.psiscontainer)} | select -expand fullname)  -match $filter |
         foreach { 
          $file_name = ($_ | split-path -leaf)
          $file_name_withoutextension =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file_name)
          $file_destination = $destination + '\' + $file_name_withoutextension
          $file_dest = ($_ | split-path -parent) -replace $source_regex,$file_destination

          if (-not (test-path $file_dest)){mkdir $file_dest}
           copy-item $_ -Destination $file_dest
        }
```

Hope this helps
Happy new year
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: Thanks! does this put the file into a different folder or the same? :O